# Spring RestTemplate - selecting MessageConverter to Use

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, restful-url

I am using the RestTemplate class to post to a JSON-based RESTful web service.  I can see from the documentation that there can be several MessageConverters available to the RestTemplate instances.  The problem I'm facing is that the client seems to be choosing to use an XML-based converter for some reason.  The "Content-Type" header is set to application/XML and the message body contains an XML representation of an object I'd like to send as JSON.  How can I most easily configure my RestTemplate instances to use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter for my requests?

Comment: What did you try? RestTemplate as its name suggests is mainly used for RESTful requests with JSON. It generally does this unless you unless configured otherwise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I set up a simple project using the same code using the RestTemplate client and it worked no problem with the correct payload and Content-Type header.  However, when used in a larger project with other Spring components wired and configured, the XML converter is used.  I'm not sure how to figure out why it's behaving that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you config `RestTemplate` via `RestTemplateBuilder`, you can use `messageConverters(org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter<?>... messageConverters)` method to config.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html#messageConverters-org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter...-

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RestTemplateBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-resttemplate.html#boot-features-resttemplate) instead of `RestTemplate`:

> The auto-configured `RestTemplateBuilder` ensures that **sensible `HttpMessageConverters` are applied to `RestTemplate` instances**.

We had this problem in our applications as soon as `jackson-dataformat-xml` was added to the dependencies, `RestTemplate` started speaking XML only (unless of course, explicitly adding `(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`). Simply switching to `RestTemplateBuilder` was an easy fix.

We did this application-wide by simply changing the configuration of the `RestTemplate` bean to be:

```java
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

Notably, this pattern also used without further explanation in the official Spring guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `MessageConverters` are available in your `ApplicationContext`. Spring most probably selects the `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` from all the message converters available, resulting in XML output.

To instruct Spring in which `MessageConverter` to use, add a content-type header to the request. For instance by performing an exchange instead of a get/postForEntity:

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

restTemplate.exchange("http://some.url", HttpMethod.GET new HttpEntity<>(headers), SomeObject.class);
```

Or by attaching a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to your RestTemplate ([example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor)). When you follow the example, be sure to use this interceptor (as in the tutorial the foo/bar is added to the *response* header):

```java
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
    httpRequest.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    return clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
}
```

Comment: I was assuming that the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter was being used (and I can confirm that by looking at some log statements).  Is this because some JAXB classes are being found on the classpath?  Doesn't it seem strange to "default" to using XML? I am using a library written by another team within the organization and don't readily have direct access to the RestTemplate being used.  Is there some way to address this with some Spring configuration somewhere at a bit of a higher level?

Comment: For optimal memory utilization, always re-use the existing constants: `headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`. Also, using `RestTemplateBuilder` may be the least invasive (although less declarative) solution here, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77316027/1246547) for details.