# How to handle � in spring boot with rest client

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate

These are my Data classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
data class Tri4Data(
    @JsonProperty("Status")
    val status: String,
    @JsonProperty("data")
    val data: Tri4JsonData
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties
data class Tri4JsonData(
    @JsonProperty("children")
    val children: List<Tri4Children>
)
data class Tri4Children(
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    val id: Int,
    @JsonProperty("Code")
    val code: String,
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    val description: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Gender")
    val gender: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Initials")
    val initials: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Surname")
    val surname: String?,
    @JsonProperty("Pracno")
    val pracNum: String?
   )
```

and this is my api request

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Tri4Data::class.java).body
```

this is the error i am receiving and i assume its from this response in the API call:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: 
Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x86
```

response

```
        {
            "ID": 27203,
            "Code": "G73.1",
            "Description": "Lambert-Eaton syndrome (C00-D48�) "
        },
```

Comment: That's invalid JSON

Answer (score 0):

Could you print response headers?

When I'm trying with latest Spring Boot app (3.2.3), I only get this behavior when the server explicitly returns header `'Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` (but then returns this UTF-8 invalid byte). If the header is not present, I'm getting different errors. So I assume that the server you're reaching to communicates that `Content-Type` is `UTF-8` but proceeds to return invalid byte as part of its response.

The `0x86` seems to be coming from `windows-1252` (or similar) and represents `†`.

Maybe, the server you're communicating with is "well-behaved" and if you specify that you accept `UTF-8`, it would return it in `UTF-8`. You can achieve that by something like:

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept-Encoding", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
HttpEntity<...> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
// and use this in restTemplate.exchange
```

If you're integrating with legacy (so it can't be changed) and ill-behaved server, then another non-standard possibility would be to implement and register custom `HttpMessageConverter` that would accept `UTF-8` encoding, but internally treat it as `windows-1252`. ([see this question for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343161/spring-resttemplate-selecting-messageconverter-to-use))

That being said, as pointed [out in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176865/how-to-handle-in-spring-boot-with-rest-client#comment137822580_78176865) - [RFC-8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1) states, that JSON should be encoded as `UTF-8`. This JSON does not conform to that, as it contains string field that is not valid `UTF-8` encoded string.

But there is room for (mis)interpretation depending on the `closed ecosystem` definition:

> JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed
> ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8